# Artisan requires me to be in the Laravel root directory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

It *appears* to me that I can only execute `artisan` if I'm in the root of the Laravel (4.1) project, and it appears to me (from looking at the source code) that this is by design, rather than a by-product of me making some mistake in how I installed things.

For instance, I copied `artisan` to my `~/bin`, but of course it uses `__DIR__` all over the place, so it complains that it can't find things like `~/bin/bootstrap/autoload.php`.

Is this correct?  Must I always go to the project root just to execute the `artisan` command?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: As each instance of artisan exists for it's installation, surely this makes sense? 4 installs of Laravel and only one artisan script... How do you propose that would work?

Comment: @DavidBarker in this case, I wrote [artisan-root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75345420/1454514), which is a small script that locates the `artisan` file in the current project structure.

Comment: @DavidRefoua that certainly makes sense, I hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 4):

You have to run the artisan from your project root, but you can be anywhere you like.

You can do this:

```
#/tmp> php /var/www/project/artisan migrate
```

But not

```
#/var/www/project/artisan> php /bin/artisan migrate
```

If you have 2 projects how could it know from which project it should run?

I've built this little app: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/artisan-anywhere

That helps you a bit. You can be at any place inside your project folder and still use artisan. So you'll be able to:

```
#/var/www/project/artisan/public/assets/css> artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call artisan outside a laravel app because it depend on some of his files to run..

**First solution: create an alias**

Simply you can add alias in your .bashrc file like so `alias artisan='php /project_folder/artisan'`.

**Second solution: create a symlink**

`$ chmod +x /project_folder/artisan` (make it executable)

`$ sudo ln -s /project_folder/artisan /usr/bin/artisan`

And then type `artisan`

Comment: Alias is the most straight forward solution

Answer (score 0):

#### A better solution

Instead of creating an alias or symlink to the artisan file of each project (which might fail if the absolute path is changed), you can use **[`artisan-root`](https://github.com/DRSDavidSoft/artisan-root/#readme)**, a small php utility I wrote that will locate the artisan file automatically, in each project.

Also, there is a [bash-only](https://gist.github.com/jhoff/8fbe4116d74931751ecc9e8203dfb7c4?permalink_comment_id=4445619#gistcomment-4445619) variant that does the same thing, but only on Linux.

#### How it works

The **artisan-root** utility is a PHP script that works by locating the `artisan` file in the current working directory, or its parent directories recursively.  This means that it'll go up one directory that either it finds the artisan file, or goes outside the project directory which in this case it'll stop with an error message.

This is a pretty standard behavior that other software like Git, or Composer (with a small additional config) use.